# SetPattern in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

> I want to set pattern like "ZZ-zz.00,ZZ"
>
> Where Z--> A-Z
>
> ```
>   z--> a-z
>
>   0--> 0-9
> ```

in EditText by this way

`

```
new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {if (UIName != null && UIName.length() > 0) {
                
                String inputFirmatValue = MobUtils.getString(dict, "inputFormat");
                for (int i = 0; i < inputFirmatValue.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals("Z")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).matches("A-Z")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(s.charAt(i)));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals("z")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).matches("a-z")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(s.charAt(i)));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals("9")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).matches("0-9")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(s.charAt(i)));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals("-")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).equals("-")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append("-"));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals(".")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).equals(".")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append("."));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (String.valueOf(inputFirmatValue.charAt(i)).equals(",")) {
                            if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).equals(",")) {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(","));
                                break;
                            } else {
                                enabledEditText.append(s.append(""));
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
//              disabledTextView.setText(s);
            }
        };`
```

and this gives no any result.

So please suggest me.

Comment: can you give your type of pattern..?

Comment: Can you please post the answer as well.